# Is there a tmux equivalent of "screen -D -R"

Tags: gnu-screen, tmux

I would like to know if there is a way to get `tmux` to behave like `screen -D -R` so I could say, have the command as a default command in Putty.

These `screen` switches would force detach of an existing screen session for my user (even if it was still active and logged-in somewhere else) and reattach it to the current session. Also, in the case that no screen session existed, it would create a new one.

I like tmux and can see clear benefits over screen, but the existence of this feature would really seal the deal.

`tmux attach` doesn't seem to create a new session if there isn't one.

The man page for tmux says:

> If no server is started, attach-session (attach) will attempt to start it;
>   **this will fail unless sessions are created in the configuration
>   file.**

What does the section in bold mean? (I can't find an example of creating a session in the conf file).

Comment: From the man page: "*The configuration file is a set of `tmux` commands which are executed in sequence when the server is first started.*" -- you could actually have `attach` or `new-session` as a line in your `.tmux.conf`.

Comment: @sr_ Well, the when the server is first started `new-session` would have just happened anyway...

Comment: Just found this (closed) question on SO. Same question with similar answers. http://stackoverflow.com/q/3432536/168034

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes: `tmux attach -d || tmux new`.

`-d` is necessary to behave like  `screen -D`, ie, detach everybody else.

Connect by ssh, then attach or create could be something like:

```
$ cat bin/stmux
#!/bin/sh
exec ssh -t "$@" 'tmux attach -d || tmux new'

$ stmux my.remote.box
```

Comment: Yes - this seems to be the most effective way to achieve the what I requested. Likewise, I disapprove of `new-session` in the config file in case you want to edit it and reload during a tmux session.

Answer (score 4):

To make `tmux attach` create a new session when there isn't one, use the option `new-session` in the tmux config file. Create the file `~/.tmux.conf` if it doesn't exist, and add

```
new-session
```

to it. Also, I alias `tmux` to `tmux attach` :)

Comment: I prefer not to have `new-session` in `~/.tmux.conf` because if I reload the configuration using command `source-file ~/.tmux.conf` (see [this](http://blog.sanctum.geek.nz/reloading-tmux-config/#comment-1461)) a new session will be launched. Yes, I can kill it and then attach to the previous one but that is a little annoying.

Answer (score 3):

You can emulate this with a shell function, this should work for any POSIX-compliant shell:

```sh
tmux() {
    if [ "$#" -ge 1 ] && [ "$1" = -z ]; then
        shift
        command tmux detach 2>/dev/null
        command tmux attach "$@" || command tmux new-session "$@"
    else
        command tmux "$@"
    fi
}
```

Now if you launch it as `tmux -z`, it should perform the actions you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

this one works a bit better for me:

```
tmux new-session -AD -s <session-name>
```

Answer (score 1):

I find this works best for me on .bashrc

```
if [[ -z $TMUX ]]; then
  tmux attach-session || tmux new-session
fi
```

Comment: How does that explain the bold section in the OP?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using this inside a .shrc file or similar with `exec` I'd recommend

```
if tmux ls
  exec tmux attach
else
  exec tmux
fi
```

Answer (score -1):

To compliment the answer from @mmoya, add this line to the end of your ~/.bashrc

```
alias tmux-dr="tmux attach -d || tmux new"
```

Open a new terminal and run `tmux-dr`

Comment: You may suggest edits to existing answers.